# Escaping regular expressions inside square brackets

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I'm trying to escape a parenthesis inside square brackets.

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9 _-\(]{1,25}$/";
$str = "TEST (ok)";

if (preg_match($pattern, $str)) {
    echo "<br />OK";
} else {
    echo "<br />FAIL";
}
```

This give me the warning:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation
>   failed: range out of order in
>   character class at offset 15 in
>   /var/www/test.php on line 6
>   FAIL

Outside the square brackets the escaping works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the hyphen as well...as written, it will match from the underscore (ASCII 95) through the left paren (ASCII 40).

Answer (score 0):

escape the hyphen or move it to the front or back of the char class list